# Formik rerender component if value changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I am showing an audio player in the form when the user records an Audio as follows:

```
{values.audioUri ? (
                <AudioSlider audio={values.audioUri} type='uri' />
              ) : null}
```

I want this player to re-render if the user records a new audio ie `values.audioUri` changes.
How can i do this in Formik?
Below is the Formik full code:

```
<Formik
          initialValues={{
            audioUri: '',
          }}
          onSubmit={addOrderHandler}
          validationSchema={validationSchema}
        >
          {({
            handleChange,
            handleBlur,
            handleSubmit,
            setFieldValue,
            values,
            errors,
            isValid,
          }) => (
           
              <AudioRecorder setFieldValue={setFieldValue} />
              {values.audioUri ? (
                <AudioSlider audio={values.audioUri} type='uri' />
              ) : null}
               <CustomButton
                onPress={handleSubmit}
                label='Submit'
                color={Colors.primary}
                style={styles.button}
              />
        )}
      </Formik>
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example of your code? At least one where the Formik part is included...

Comment: sure i will update the question. Thank you

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem. `<AudioSlider/>` _is_ rerendering whenever `values.audioUri` changes, because you are passing it down as a prop, and whenever a prop changes the component will re-render. So what is exactly what you want to achieve and you can't manage?

Comment: the weird thing is that it was not rerendering when the prop changes. i would solve that with a useEffect hook but the component is built with class based which am not very profficient in. Anyway i solved the prolem by creating a delete recording action inside the recorder which set the value of the audioUri to null and thus hided the component with the iffy. Thanks for trying to help

Comment: my question would be in general if i can make an iffy with a formik value toggle (compare previous state to current state somehow) sorry am a bit of a begginer